# О звании города

Tags: общие-вопросы

Правомочно ли выражение : "Город-герой Санкт-Петербург"? Подскажите, как следует правильно говорить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, корректно будет "Город-герой Ленинград (ныне Санкт-Петербург)".

Почетное звание  установлено 8 мая 1965 года, когда Президиум Верховного Совета СССР своим Указом утвердил Положение о высшей степени отличия — звании «город-герой». В этот же день Ленинграду, Волгограду (бывш. Сталинграду), Севастополю, Одессе, Киеву, Москве и Брестской крепости были вручены медали «Золотая Звезда», а Москве и Брестской крепости были также присвоены звания «город-герой» и «крепость-герой» соответственно.

Comment: Вы коротко ответили, поэтому немного добавлю. Ленинград, Сталинград, Севастополь и Одесса названы городами-героями в приказе ВГ от 1 мая 1945. Киев - в указе ПВС СССР от 21 июня 1961.  
Интересная деталь : салют в честь космического полета Ю.Гагарина производился в городе-герое **Сталинграде**! Может, и его стоит так официально именовать?

Comment: Не думаю.Надо называть так, как назывался город в 1961-1965 г.(как написано в документе о присвоении звания), т.е. город-герой Волгоград (бывший Сталинград)

Comment: При Хрущеве после переименования Сталинграда и битву стали называть Волгоградской. Потом, конечно, одумались.